# traffic analizer website use python2 with django

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django and i don't know very much about it. I wrote a Python program which decode network traffic (with pcapy and socket)and designed a interface in django for it. now i don't know how to put Python program on my website and how can I create a table to display captured traffic details (the number of table rows is not clear because traffic is received on the interface  ), please help me
Thanks alot,
python code is like this sample :
http://www.binarytides.com/code-a-packet-sniffer-in-python-with-pcapy-extension/

Comment: Do you want to capture the data and put it in the template.. ah ?

Comment: This is a very broad question. When would the python script be called? After some request, in a cron? Also there are security implications i you would allow a web page to run such scripts.

Comment: execuse me,i confuse how ask my question,i wrote program that select interface and capture traffic on it and decode it,now i have website and i want put this code in it,(in checkbox user select the interface and the capture start)and in table show the traffic and its details,i dont'know how do it?

Comment: Nobody's here to help me?

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this repo ( https://github.com/nitinnath/python-pusher-traffic-monitor ), and find the app.py file, compile it on your mind :p , hope it will help you